# How to create collection of abstract class type objects

Tags: powershell, generic-list, custom-object

I'm writing a powershell script on Microsofts WHCK 2.0 API. I'm from perl background so do not know much in powershell or c#.

Well, my code is:

```
$ObjectModel  = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($env:WTTSTDIO + "microsoft.windows.Kits.Hardware.objectmodel.dll")
$DbConnection = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($env:WTTSTDIO + "microsoft.windows.Kits.Hardware.objectmodel.dbconnection.dll")
$Submission   = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($env:WTTSTDIO + "microsoft.windows.Kits.Hardware.objectmodel.submission.dll")
```

## And a little bit later.

```
   $List = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.List``1[Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.ObjectModel.Target]"
```

When I run this code, it produces this error:

"New-Object: Cannot find type: [System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.ObjectModel.Target]]: make sure the aseembly containing this type is loaded."

I've verified that the aseemblies are loaded correctly, using CurrentDomain.getAssemblies() method.
Also I have verified that the type "Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.ObjectModel.Target" is present in "Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.ObjectModel.dll" assembly, as:

```
$ObjectModel.GetTypes() | % { 
      if($_.FullName -eq "Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.ObjectModel.Target")
      { 
          $found=1
      }
}
```

One more thing I would like to mention, "Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.ObjectModel.Target" this type/class is an abstract class.

I've searched a lot but couldnt get the right way to get rid of this error. Please suggest and help overcoming this error.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$List = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.ObjectModel.Target]'
```

Comment: Hi Christian, tried that too, but getting same error.

Tried this:
$List=New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List``1[System.Object]'
and it worked.

But when I replace "System.Object" with "Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.ObjectModel.Target", it doesnt work. :(

Comment: If you do `$a = new-obect 'Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.ObjectModel.Target'` got some error?

Comment: yes, there is an error:

"New-Object: Constructor not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type microsoft.windows.kits.hardware.objectmodel.target"

Comment: Check out the sample script microsoft has provided in WHCK documentation, at "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj123504.aspx#BKMK_PS_CreateSubmissionPackage" under Windows Powershell section and under heading "Create a submission package from a project".

When I asked Microsoft people about this error, they said it is working fine at their side, so whats wrong at my side, i'm not getting that.

Comment: In the link I see just `$targetList = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.List``1[Target]"` ... have you tried like this?

Comment: Do I need to do Add-type on this type, i.e. 'Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.ObjectModel.Target' ?